# can a custom jsp tag have access to the name of the jsp calling it?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I'm creating a debugging tool that logs output for a specific (and commonly used) jsp tag. It would be helpful if i could also log the name of the jsp page and the line number where the custom tag is called.

Is it possible to get access to the jsp name and line number where a custom tag is called from inside the custom tag?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not get a line number, where a custom tag is called.

Also you can not get **exact** JSP name, but via **PageContext** object, which is available to you in **TagSupport**, you can get servlet name (which will look like '*index_jsp*'):

```
((Servlet)pageContext.getPage()).getServletConfig().getServletName()
```

But this is not specified in any specification, so naming scheme differs between JSP containers.